# Scale view to fit window

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, roassal

I use Roassal graphs in Glamour panes, and I wonder if there is a way to
zoom and center the Roassal graph so that it fits entirely into its Glamour
pane. Can this be done?

Comment: I've been wondering that myself ;)

Comment: @MartinW I've asked on the mailing list if anybody has something against me asking this on SO. No one replied

Comment: I don’t mind, just wanted to say hello. And thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell if you set:

- **realExtent** to the size of the window
- **extent** as the size of view (all it's elements aka `view encompassingRectangle`)

an then open a view, it should work

Comment: It seems to get in the right direction - but when i follow your approach (and add a bit to maintain the original aspect ratio) the visualisation shows some drawing errors (not the red morphic error - but some blanc spots in the drawing), expecially when you drag the view around afterwards.